# Api to encode response in django

Tags: json, encode

I need a Encoded JsonResponse in Django. For example, i have model called user it returns the response as serialized list.

If this was my model and serializer and view:

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField(max_length=100, default=None)

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

def user_api(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        users = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        json_data = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)
        return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

I will get response like this from my model:
{
"id":1,
"name":"helloworld"
}

But,I need like this:
{
"id":1
"name":"jhdfdvhgdhiu"
}
the value should be encoded and need to return as JsonResponse.

Thanks:)
I have tried the below but didn't get the expected

```
class JsonEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    # overload method default
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime):
            return obj.isoformat()
        elif isinstance(obj, Decimal):
            return float(Decimal(obj).quantize(Decimal("0.01"), ROUND_UP))
        elif isinstance(obj, QuerySet):
            return JsonEncoder().encode(obj.value)
        return JsonEncoder.default(self, obj)


def json_encode(data):
    return json.dumps(data, cls=JsonEncoder)
```